# Graphene_django Mutatation

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm trying to make a mutation of user model via graphql (graphene_django).
Here is a code sample.

```
class UserMutation(graphene.Mutation):
  class Arguments:
      email = graphene.String(required=True)
      name = graphene.String(required=True)
      age = graphene.String(required=True)

  user = graphene.Field(UserType)

  def mutate(self, info, email, name, age):
    ok = True
    user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    user.email = email
    user.name = name
    user.age = age
    user.save()

    return UserMutation(ok=ok, user=user)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
   create_user = UserMutation.Field()
```

So, the problem is it doesn't work. When I try to make a mutation:

```
mutation CreateUser($email: String!, $name: String!, $age: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email, name: $name, age: $age) {
     email
     name
     age
  }
}
```

Variables are:

```
{
  "email": "lavrikrom2@gmail.com",
  "name": "Roma",
  "age": "25"
}
```

It returns me an error:

```
  {
    "message": "Unknown argument \"email\" on field \"createUser\" of type \"Mutation\".",
    "locations": [
      {
         "line": 33,
         "column": 14
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or you can see the playground
[image]

But I specified arguments in mutate function. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: "But I specified arguments in mutate function." - proof?

Comment: @xadm sorry, Edited description

Comment: poor proof ... does it work in playground (using variables of course)? compare network requests details

Comment: I am testing it on a playground, resolvers work fine

Comment: then compare network requests details (from playground and from code)

Comment: all the same, request sends fine, 
operationName: CreateUser, 
query
variables

Comment: ok, we know it works the same (we eliminated client problem) ... I don't know python ... but I think you should check syntax, IMHO you have **bad indentation** - check docs

Comment: ok, thanks for help, I really appreciate it. I will write here if I solve this

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out what problem was.

I haven't specified on which field I want to make mutation. I my case it was user. So, the right mutation should look like this(with specifying variables, of course):

```
mutation UserMutation($email: String!, $name: String!, $age: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email, name: $name, age: $age) {
    user {
      email
      name
      age
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I needed to make some changes in the code as well:

```
class UserField(graphene.ObjectType): 
   email = graphene.String(required=True)
   name = graphene.String(required=True)
   age = graphene.String(required=True)

class UserMutation(graphene.Mutation):
  class Arguments:
      email = graphene.String(required=True)
      name = graphene.String(required=True)
      age = graphene.String(required=True)

  ok = graphene.Boolean()
  user = graphene.Field(lambda: UserField)

  def mutate(self, info, email, name, age):
    ok = True
    user = User(email=email, name=name, age=age)
    user.save()

    return UserMutation(ok=ok, user=user)
```